# Local storage being read too many times

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write the values of checkboxes to local storage and then retrieve them. Setting the values works fine. However, when I try to access local storage it accesses it too many times and the number of times it accesses it increments each time the function is called. For example, the first time the function is called a single array is printed to the console. The second time 2 arrays are printed, the third time three arrays are printed and so on.

My subsequent code goes on to display the items from the array in an HTML list, therefore, having multiple arrays confuses it and duplicates the data

Any clue how I can prevent the array from being generated multiple times?
I have attempted to remove the for loop to see if that is the cause but this makes no difference. As far as I am aware it is a problem with the first part but I am not too sure where

```
$("#confirm-button").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if (localStorage.length===0) {
        createAlbum();
    }
    else if (localStorage.length>0) {
        document.getElementById("confirmation").style.display="block";
        $("#Yes").click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            localStorage.clear();
            createAlbum();
            document.getElementById("confirmation").style.display="none";
        })
        $("#No").click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            document.getElementById("confirmation").style.display="none";
        })
    }
});

function createAlbum(){
    if ($("li input:checkbox:checked").length===0){
        alert("You have not selected any songs. Please select at least one song")
    }
    else if ($("li input:checkbox:checked").length>0) {
        var searchIDs = $("li input:checkbox:checked").map(function () {
            return $(this).val();
        }).get();
        localStorage.setItem('searchIDs', JSON.stringify(searchIDs));
        retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('searchIDs');
        var information = JSON.parse(retrievedObject);
        console.log(information);
        $('#overlay_text').append("<ol id='newList'></ol>");
        for (var i = 0; i < information.length; i++) {
            var item = document.createElement('li');
            item.append(information[i]);
            $('#newList').append(item);
        }
      }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="overlay">
    <div id="overlay_text">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="confirmation">
    <div id="confirmation-text">
    An album already exists are you sure you want to overwrite it?
    <button id="Yes">Yes</button>
    <button id="No">No</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

Included the code that calls the function. The first bit is to check if any values currently exist in local storage. If no values exist the function is called. If values do exist the user is then asked if they wish to overwrite this data. 'confirmation' is the window that displays the message about overwriting data to the user

Comment: Sounds more like event listeners being added multiple times. But don't see why you have to get same data immediately after you just set it. Why don't you set `var information=searchIDs `?

Comment: The code of the function looks OK, can you include the code that calls the function? Like @charlietfl said, perhaps you are adding multiple event listeners that call this function

Comment: Provide a runnable [mcve] that reproduces the problem

Comment: @charlietfl I have added the code that calls the function. I also attempted to set var information=searchIDs but this did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your problem is a result of creating event listeners inside the handler of another event. This is a bad practice in general

Every time the confirm button is clicked you add a new listener to the Yes/No buttons and thus the event handlers for Yes/No are getting called multiple times (once for every time user clicks on confirm)

Move your Yes/No click listeners outside of `$("#confirm-button").click` or use `off()` before adding a new `click`

```
$("#Yes").off('click').on('click', function(event){...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are adding the events every time when a user clicks on the confirm-button try moving the functions `$("#Yes").click(function(event)` and `$("#No").click(function(event)` out of the `$("#confirm-button").click(function(event)`.